# Jenkins 1.596.3 with java 1.6.24 and web logic 10.3.5, version compatibility

Tags: java, jenkins, weblogic-10.x, continuous-deployment, oracle-soa

[image: EAR file and it has the jenkins.war]I am working on build automation of oracle SOA 11 g application with jenkins 1.596.3 and java 1.6.24 and web logic 10.3.5.

After deploying the war file called jenkins into web logic results file Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, yes I understood that it's because of different java versions but my system is configured with 1.6.24 jdk.

As I don't have any prior knowledge of jenkins, I started to backtrack everything,

extracting all files from ear file (jenkins) and I checked the classes compiler version by using javap command then the output was version 47 means jdk 1.3.

I don't have source to recompile those classes from jenkins..

what to do now ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated
TIA

Comment: Have you already checked this page [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Weblogic). The version problems seems to come from the classes inside `winstone.jar`.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hudson/WebAppMain : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, I am getting this above error in web logic console while trying to deploy

Comment: Just for info: Jenkins 1.596.3 is getting to be fairly old, and there have been a number of major security updates since then.

Answer (score 1):

The Jenkins version (1.596.3) and the class version (51.0) in the `UnsupportedClassVersionError` do not match. Do you have maybe another (newer) Jenkins deployed before?

```
# download https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/1.596.3/jenkins.war
jar xf jenkins.1.596.3.war WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.596.3.jar
cd WEB-INF/lib
jar xf jenkins-core-1.596.3.jar hudson/WebAppMain.class
javap -v hudson/WebAppMain.class | grep -i "version:"
```

returns

```
minor version: 0
major version: 50
```

Which indicate the class is compiled for Java 1.6.

Comment: even I am also getting the same version 50 , but while deploying ear file into web logic it is showing the java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hudson/WebAppMain : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Comment: @Sai Which `ear` file do you deploy? In your initial post you spoke about the `war` file.

Comment: sorry my mistake I created EAR file which contains jenkins.war (i attached screen shot for project  structure )